# How to generate yaml template with kubectl command?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, kubectl

Is it possible to generate yaml with kubernetes kubectl command ? to clarify - I'm not talking about generating yaml from existing deployments like kubectl get XXXX -o yaml, but merely about generating yamls for the very first time for pod, service, ingress, etc.

PS There is a way to get yaml files from kubernetes.io site ( [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/simple_deployment.yaml) , [2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/application/update_deployment.yaml) ) but I am looking if there is a way to generate yamls templates with kubectl only.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's the command `create` in `kubectl` that does the trick and replaced the `run` used in the past: let's image you want to create a *Deployment* running a *nginx:latest* Docker image.

```
# kubectl create deployment my_deployment --image=busybox --dry-run=client --output=yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: my_deployment
  name: my_deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my_deployment
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: my_deployment
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: busybox
        name: busybox
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Let's analyze each parameter:

- `my_deployment` is the *Deployment* name you chose
- `--image` is the Docker image you want to deploy
- `--dry-run=client` won't execute the resource creation, used mainly for validation.  Replace 'client' with 'true' for older versions of Kubernetes. Neither `client` nor `server` will actually create the resource, though `server` will return an error if the resource cannot be created without a dry run (ie: resource already exists). The difference is very subtle.
- `--output=yaml` prints to *standard output* the YAML definition of the *Deployment* resource.

Obviously, you can perform this options just with few Kubernetes default resources:

```
# kubectl create 
  clusterrole         Create a ClusterRole.
  clusterrolebinding  Create a ClusterRoleBinding for a particular ClusterRole
  configmap           Create a configmap from a local file, directory or literal value
  deployment          Create a deployment with the specified name.
  job                 Create a job with the specified name.
  namespace           Create a namespace with the specified name
  poddisruptionbudget Create a pod disruption budget with the specified name.
  priorityclass       Create a priorityclass with the specified name.
  quota               Create a quota with the specified name.
  role                Create a role with single rule.
  rolebinding         Create a RoleBinding for a particular Role or ClusterRole
  secret              Create a secret using specified subcommand
  service             Create a service using specified subcommand.
  serviceaccount      Create a service account with the specified name
```

According to this, you can render the template without the prior need of deploying your resource.

Answer (score 28):

Also `kubectl explain` can be used for different resources. It will not generate an yaml file for a standard pod, but it will display a description for one, e.g.:

```
kubectl explain pods
```

for getting details for a section/property in the pod:

```
kubectl explain pods.spec
```

One can also output the resulting explanation to an yaml file and edit that:

```
kubectl explain pods > mypod.yaml
```

AND!
with

```
kubectl explain pod --recursive
```

one gets the whole structure of a resource without the explaining; exporting to a yaml file can represent an empty skeleton for the intended resource; below a segment for the pod:

```
KIND:     Pod
VERSION:  v1

DESCRIPTION:
     Pod is a collection of containers that can run on a host. This resource is
     created by clients and scheduled onto hosts.

FIELDS:
   apiVersion   <string>
   kind <string>
   metadata <Object>
      annotations   <map[string]string>
      clusterName   <string>
      creationTimestamp <string>
      deletionGracePeriodSeconds    <integer>
      deletionTimestamp <string>
      finalizers    <[]string>
      generateName  <string>
      generation    <integer>
      labels    <map[string]string>
      managedFields <[]Object>
         apiVersion <string>
         fieldsType <string>
         fieldsV1   <map[string]>
         manager    <string>
         operation  <string>
         time   <string>
      name  <string>
      namespace <string>
      ownerReferences   <[]Object>
         apiVersion <string>
         blockOwnerDeletion <boolean>
         controller <boolean>
         kind   <string>
         name   <string>
         uid    <string>
      resourceVersion   <string>
      selfLink  <string>
      uid   <string>
   spec <Object>
      activeDeadlineSeconds <integer>
      affinity  <Object>
         nodeAffinity   <Object>
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution <[]Object>
               preference   <Object>
                  matchExpressions  <[]Object>
                     key    <string>
                     operator   <string>
                     values <[]string>
                  matchFields   <[]Object>
                     key    <string>
                     operator   <string>
                     values <[]string>
               weight   <integer>
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution  <Object>
               nodeSelectorTerms    <[]Object>
                  matchExpressions  <[]Object>
                     key    <string>
                     operator   <string>
                     values <[]string>
                  matchFields   <[]Object>
                     key    <string>
                     operator   <string>
                     values <[]string>
         podAffinity    <Object>
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution <[]Object>
               podAffinityTerm  <Object>
                  labelSelector <Object>
                     matchExpressions   <[]Object>
                        key <string>
                        operator    <string>
                        values  <[]string>
                     matchLabels    <map[string]string>
                  namespaces    <[]string>
                  topologyKey   <string>
               weight   <integer>
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution  <[]Object>
               labelSelector    <Object>
                  matchExpressions  <[]Object>
                     key    <string>
                     operator   <string>
                     values <[]string>
                  matchLabels   <map[string]string>
               namespaces   <[]string>
               topologyKey  <string>
         podAntiAffinity    <Object>
            preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution <[]Object>
               podAffinityTerm  <Object>
                  labelSelector <Object>
                     matchExpressions   <[]Object>
                        key <string>
                        operator    <string>
                        values  <[]string>
                        .
                        .
                        .
```

Comment: your answer is awesome. That command not only specify the fields, also explain them. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [yq tool](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) to generate yaml template without specific metadata (or other fields), based on existing resource. For example:

```
kubectl get deploy my-nginx -o yaml | \
yq eval 'del(.metadata.resourceVersion, .metadata.uid, .metadata.annotations, .metadata.creationTimestamp, .metadata.selfLink, .metadata.managedFields, .status.conditions)' \
- > nginx_template.yaml
```

Later you can apply that resource with `kubectl apply -f nginx_template.yaml`. It works well with other resource types, including *CustomResourceDefinitions*.

*(I know it's not exactly answering OP question, but the subject might lead here people looking for this particular answer).*